# How to set rollover value for Python Bokeh chart

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm building a python Flask streaming server with Bokeh charts.

I've managed to do so with the `AjaxDataSource` class, however I need to set a limit for data to be displayed, like the rollover value in the `stream` method

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/_modules/bokeh/models/sources.html#ColumnDataSource.stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want the `max_size` property of `AjaxDataSource`? It is described in the reference guide:

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/sources.html#bokeh.models.sources.AjaxDataSource.max_size

The reference guide is a good resource when you need to find out specific details about something you already have some knowledge about.

Comment: If there's better wording or improvements we can make please open an issue a PR https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues